# Need an explanation of Grundy numbers from Competitive Programming Handbook

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to understand the example from the book https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf at page 239 .
The example is described as follows:
[image]

What I don't get is just what exactly, say, number 3 next to lower right corner means, we can move 4 steps up and 3 steps left from it, how is it 3? Same for 4 just above it, it doesn't correspond to any set of moves I can think of. The book in general makes a lot of leaps of logic they think are obvious but usually I can infer what they mean after some time, here I am just lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for computing these numbers is recursive.

You consider all the values you can reach, and then pick the smallest (non-negative) integer that is not reachable.

For example, the value in the top-left corner is 0 because no moves are possible.

For example, the value next to lower right is 3 because the reachable values are 0,4,1,0,2,1,4 so 3 is the smallest integer not in this list.

This explains how to compute the numbers, but to understand them it is probably better to start with understanding the game of [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim).  In the game of Nim, the Sprague Grundy number for a pile is simply equal to the size of a pile.

Comment: Hm, so to recreate the table we should recursively go from a terminating state(upper left), either assigning 0 if we are in a losing state of the next smallest unreachable integer, right?

Comment: Yes: by the way, if you like this kind of thing, I can highly recommend "Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays" for a deep and fascinating exploration of the subject.